# Action ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE shows package names instead of AppNames

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, package-managers

when I crete TAKE PHOTO implicit intent, a intent chooser window appear properly. Unfortunatelly, it shows package names instead of application names. Any idea what I doing wrong? Thanks.

Everything is working (intent, camera app, image returned to onActivityResult, ...).
If there is only one camera app - no choose is shown and camera app is called directly (correct).
Camera application which I have installed are: default android camera, Google Camera.
Tested on 3 different samsung phones.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(PoiDetailGalleryFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "Error occurred while creating the File", ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be a language issue? If you switch to English UI, does this still show package names?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this issue is linked with the Samsung devices, they don't show application name but the package name only.

the Google Nexus devices behave differently, they show the application name and the package name together.